# Stop header/nav bar from scrolling

Tags: css

Ok so I have header/nav bar which scrolls up/down with each page.  How do I simply fix it to top of page so it no longer scrolls and content scrolls behind it?  I checked out so many examples but most are very old and dont seem to work.
I want the entire header incl. nav bar just to remain in fixed position!

Appreciate any help.
Thanks Damien

```
<header> 
    <div class="nav-responsive"><div>MENU</div>
        <select onchange="location=this.value">
            <option></option>
            <option value="index.html">Home</option>
            <option value="about.html">About</option>
            <option value="services.html">Services</option>
            <option value="products.html">Products</option>
            <option value="contacts.html">Contacts</option>
        </select>
    </div>
   <div> 
      <div>                     
          <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/JungleDesign.png" alt=""></a></h1> 
          <nav>  
            <ul class="menu">
                  <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Damien... simple google search... http://cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/

Comment: What CSS have you tried with your HTML?

Comment: Tried that and several others from Google search but none work?  Will try a few more now and see :)

Comment: Fixing header or footer to top or bottom is simply adding `position: absolute; top: 0;` for example...

Answer (score 5):

Use fixed position

```
header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And following after header element you can manage your top spacing with `padding-top: {{header-height}}`

Comment: what element am i applying padding to?

Comment: what element is your after header?

Comment: My only problem now is that the slider which is positioned below the header is blocking the header, the header is behind it but once I scroll down past the slider the header reappears and all the remaining content scrolls behind it in the correct way.  So it seems that the slider is causing me a problem?

Comment: #slide {width:100%;  
  height:496px; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  z-index:777;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background:#fff;
  border-bottom:#fff 1px solid;
  margin-top:200;
  }

.slider {width:1080px; 
  height:496px;
  overflow:hidden; 
  position:relative; 
  margin:0 auto;
  }

Answer (score 0):

add a fixed class to `<header class="fixed-header">` then in CSS:

```
.fixed-header { position: fixed; }
```

Comment: When I do that the header disappears behind the slider element and only appears again when I scroll past the slider.  Even then the content scrolls over the header and not behind it?

Comment: Ok so I out the following in my css.                                                                                                                                     header {position: fixed; z-index:300; background-color:#fff;}

Comment: The problem seems to be with the slider positioned directly below the header/nav bar.  The header completely disappears but once I scroll past the slider it reappears and works fine.  Do I need to reposition the slider?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but I solved it myself, it was because the Slider had a higher Z rank than the header.  All fine now!!